# alter table error ERROR 1347 (HY000): 'table-name' is not BASE TABLE in mysql

Tags: mysql, alter-table

Recently I attempted to add a column to one of the tables of my database which has 316 table but after the following command:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE view_Server ADD rsh_protocol VARCHAR(60);
```

I get the following error :

```
ERROR 1347 (HY000): 'itop.view_Server' is not BASE TABLE
```

all my searches was unsuccessful like using ``` '``' ```. So the question is that what's the reason of this error? and how can I git ride of that?

Comment: In order to change a view, you need to change the query definition of the view. You may need to alter the base table that the view is relying on,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your "table" name, are you trying to add a column to a view?

Run through each of these:

```
CREATE TABLE x (id INT, name VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO x VALUES (1, 'One');
INSERT INTO x VALUES (2, 'Two');

-- A view with no change of column names
CREATE VIEW y AS SELECT id FROM x;

SELECT * FROM y;

-- Change the view, again using the base table column names
ALTER VIEW y AS SELECT name FROM x;

SELECT * FROM y;

-- Change the view, switching column name from `name` to `theName`
ALTER VIEW y (theName) AS SELECT name FROM x;

SELECT * FROM y;

-- Change the view, switching column name to `anotherName` by aliasing in the SELECT
ALTER VIEW y AS SELECT name anotherName FROM x;

SELECT * FROM y;
```

Comment: What would be after `AS SELECT`?